# Can't install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 because it says I have multiple operating systems

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am completely new to Ubuntu but am looking forward to giving it a shot.

I downloaded 12.04 64-bit and burned it to a DVD. Booted my laptop from the DVD and tried to install it alongside Windows 7 64-bit, but it says that my laptop has multiple OS and it only gives me the option to either *erase the disk and install* or the *advanced install*.

As far as I know the only OS I have is Windows 7 64-bit. Has this happened to anyone else? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have low hard disk space?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the advanced install and your hard drive partition information will appear. You could have a recovery partition that is preventing Ubuntu from automatically making a partition for you. Post the hard drive info that the advanced installation option reports if you want some help deciding how to install.

Comment: You should post it as comment as this doesn't answer the question. If you need more info, use `comment`